# XPath text and nodes in real order

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath

I want to process an HTML node by XPath. I'm using python.

```
<p>Hi, find your product <a href="/external.php">here</a>. Or visit <em>main website</em> more times.</p>
```

I want to extract composition of the `p` element, to get values in a list:

1. **text**: *Hi, find your product*
2. **node `a`** (I will take `@href` later)
3. **text**: *. Or visit*
4. **node `em`** (I will take `text()` later)
5. **text**:  *more times.*

I tried to use `block.xpath("./text()")` – got just `['Hi, find your product ','. Or visit ',' more times.']`

Then, `block.xpath("./*[self::a or self::em]")` – got just `a` and `em` elements, no text.

How to build an XPath query to get text and needed nodes in correct order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
/p/node()
```

will select all the node children of the root `p` element, as requested